# Single cycle mips, store word(sw) control values, why MemRead is 0 and not "don't care"?

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

I have a quick question, the book I have shows the control values for a store word instruction as such :

```
Regdst - X
Alusrc 1
Memto-reg X
RegWrite 0
-> MemRead 0
MemWrite 1
Branch 0
ALUOp1 0
ALUOp2 0
```

The explanation for *memto-reg* to be "*don't care*" is because  *RegWrite* is 0 anyway, makes sense. But my question is, why *MemRead* is 0 ?

As *MemRead* only puts a value on the *ReadData* output, and I shouldn't care what value it is for the same reason I shouldn't care what value is after the  *MemtoReg* mux choice, as *RegWrite* is 0 anyway.

**My question is: shouldn't *MemRead* be don't care instead of 0?** And the book made a mistake ? Or am I missing something, because I see in more sources that *MemRead* is 0 and not don't care in store word(sw) instruction.

FYI: the figure is missing some control datapaths like RegDst Mux but irrelevant to the question I think. Also, same question applies to beq instruction.

[image]

Comment: Kudos for making a self contained and clear question! I believe that MemWrite and MemRead must be mutually exclusive. Contrary to registers, in simple architectures memory is usually single ported and the storage technology, say DRAM, usually doesn't allow for a read while a write is being performed. Out of the four possible combinations for MemWrite/Read, 00 means nop, 01 means Read, 10 means Write and 11 is not allowed. Is there anything in the book that could suggest this?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Oh that's it thanks ! I suspected it too but not enough to look specifically for this, it is mentioned in the book that only one of the read/write controls may be asserted on any given clock, because " reading the value of an invalid address can cause problems..."